# Which is the correct formula to solve probability problem?

Tags: probability

*Question*

Suppose you toss a coin four times. The sample space

$$Ω = {HHHH, HHHT, HHT H, . . . , T T T T }$$ contains 16 outcomes and you should assume each outcome is equally likely.

Let X be the Binomial random variable that corresponds to the number of heads in an outcome,

e.g., X(HT HT) = 2.

Let Y be the Bernoulli random variable that evaluates to 1 if there is an even number of heads in the outcome, e.g., Y (HHHT) = 0 and Y (HT HT) = 1.

What is the value of P(X = 3)?

Is this formula correct for in this instance?

$$P(X = k)  =  {4 \choose 3} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 \left(1- \frac{1}{2}\right)^{4-3} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct. In the specific case where the two outcomes are equally likely, $P(X = x)$ can be computed just by using the choice function to find the number of successful outcomes and dividing by the size of the solution space. Here, $P(X = 3) = \binom{4}{3}/16 = \frac{1}{4}$.